# Fedora 19 - Booting doesn't show login screen

Tags: boot, fedora, kdm

I have done some common updates in my system, and now I have the problem detailed below.

It starts as usual, loading services, but when trying to launch the login screen (I use KDE), it stops and shows me once more the starting services screen, where it blocks after some time.

I could go to another tty, login as root and do the following commands:

```
init 3
init 5
```

And it starts as expected. But every time I restart, I have to do the same thing to see my desktop.

I have seen my `/var/log/boot.log` file and I haven't seen anything unusual. There is it:

```
[  OK  ] Found device SAMSUNG_HD204UI.
[  OK  ] Found device SAMSUNG_HD204UI.
[  OK  ] Found device SAMSUNG_HD204UI.
[  OK  ] Started dracut initqueue hook.
         Mounting /sysroot...
[  OK  ] Started Show Plymouth Boot Screen.
[  OK  ] Reached target Paths.
[  OK  ] Reached target Basic System.
[  OK  ] Mounted /sysroot.
[  OK  ] Reached target Initrd Root File System.
         Starting Reload Configuration from the Real Root...
[  OK  ] Started Reload Configuration from the Real Root.
[  OK  ] Reached target Initrd File Systems.
[  OK  ] Reached target Initrd Default Target.

Welcome to [0;34mFedora 19 (Schrödinger’s Cat)!

[  OK  ] Stopped Switch Root.
[  OK  ] Stopped target Switch Root.
[  OK  ] Stopped target Initrd File Systems.
[  OK  ] Stopped target Initrd Root File System.
         Starting Collect Read-Ahead Data...
         Starting Replay Read-Ahead Data...
[  OK  ] Reached target Login Prompts.
[  OK  ] Reached target Remote File Systems.
[  OK  ] Listening on Syslog Socket.
[  OK  ] Listening on Delayed Shutdown Socket.
[  OK  ] Listening on /dev/initctl Compatibility Named Pipe.
         Mounting Debug File System...
         Starting Create static device nodes in /dev...
[  OK  ] Set up automount Arbitrary Executable File Formats F...utomount Point.
         Mounting Huge Pages File System...
         Mounting POSIX Message Queue File System...
[  OK  ] Listening on udev Kernel Socket.
[  OK  ] Listening on udev Control Socket.
         Starting udev Coldplug all Devices...
[  OK  ] Listening on LVM2 metadata daemon socket.
[  OK  ] Listening on Device-mapper event daemon FIFOs.
         Starting Monitoring of LVM2 mirrors, snapshots etc. ...ress polling...
         Expecting device dev-disk-by\x2duuid-06995479\x2d888...de5ee.device...
         Mounting Temporary Directory...
         Expecting device dev-disk-by\x2duuid-f88e071f\x2ddb3...1d57c.device...
         Expecting device dev-disk-by\x2duuid-5c6ae9c2\x2d610...c99fb.device...
         Expecting device dev-disk-by\x2dlabel-Documentos.device...
         Expecting device dev-disk-by\x2dlabel-Programas.device...
         Expecting device dev-disk-by\x2dlabel-Extra.device...
[  OK  ] Stopped Trigger Flushing of Journal to Persistent Storage.
         Stopping Journal Service...
[  OK  ] Stopped Journal Service.
         Starting Journal Service...
[  OK  ] Started Journal Service.
[  OK  ] Started Collect Read-Ahead Data.
[  OK  ] Started Replay Read-Ahead Data.
         Starting Load legacy module configuration...
         Starting File System Check on Root Device...
         Starting Apply Kernel Variables...
         Mounting Configuration File System...
         Starting Set Up Additional Binary Formats...
         Starting LVM2 metadata daemon...
[  OK  ] Mounted Temporary Directory.
[  OK  ] Mounted Configuration File System.
[  OK  ] Mounted Debug File System.
[  OK  ] Mounted Huge Pages File System.
[  OK  ] Mounted POSIX Message Queue File System.
[  OK  ] Started udev Coldplug all Devices.
         Starting udev Wait for Complete Device Initialization...
         Mounting Arbitrary Executable File Formats File System...
[  OK  ] Started LVM2 metadata daemon.
[  OK  ] Started Apply Kernel Variables.
[  OK  ] Started Load legacy module configuration.
[    8.501835] systemd-fsck[261]: Fedora_19: clean, 964326/4825088 files, 8824281/19283456 blocks
[  OK  ] Started File System Check on Root Device.
         Starting Remount Root and Kernel File Systems...
[  OK  ] Started Remount Root and Kernel File Systems.
         Starting Configure read-only root support...
[  OK  ] Started Monitoring of LVM2 mirrors, snapshots etc. u...ogress polling.
[  OK  ] Mounted Arbitrary Executable File Formats File System.
[  OK  ] Started Set Up Additional Binary Formats.
[  OK  ] Started Create static device nodes in /dev.
         Starting udev Kernel Device Manager...
[  OK  ] Started udev Kernel Device Manager.
[  OK  ] Reached target Local File Systems (Pre).
[  OK  ] Started Configure read-only root support.
         Starting Load Random Seed...
[  OK  ] Started Load Random Seed.
[  OK  ] Started udev Wait for Complete Device Initialization.
         Starting Activation of DM RAID sets...
[  OK  ] Reached target Sound Card.
[  OK  ] Started Activation of DM RAID sets.
[  OK  ] Reached target Encrypted Volumes.
[  OK  ] Found device SAMSUNG_HD204UI.
         Activating swap /dev/disk/by-uuid/06995479-888f-4e3f...99fa3c5de5ee...
[  OK  ] Found device SAMSUNG_HD204UI.
         Starting File System Check on /dev/disk/by-uuid/5c6a...d143aacc99fb...
[  OK  ] Found device SAMSUNG_HD204UI.
         Starting File System Check on /dev/disk/by-uuid/f88e...fe923f01d57c...
[  OK  ] Activated swap /dev/disk/by-uuid/06995479-888f-4e3f-b62c-99fa3c5de5ee.
[  OK  ] Reached target Swap.
[   12.871604] systemd-fsck[375]: /dev/sda7: clean, 89896/2411920 files, 3370321/9640192 blocks
[  OK  ] Found device SAMSUNG_HD204UI.
         Mounting /media/Documentos...
[  OK  ] Found device SAMSUNG_HD204UI.
         Mounting /media/Extra...
[  OK  ] Started File System Check on /dev/disk/by-uuid/5c6ae...d-d143aacc99fb.
         Mounting /home...
[   13.813950] systemd-fsck[379]: BOOT: clean, 374/64768 files, 28850/258822 blocks
         Mounting FUSE Control File System...
[  OK  ] Mounted FUSE Control File System.
[  OK  ] Found device SAMSUNG_HD204UI.
         Mounting /media/Programas...
[  OK  ] Started File System Check on /dev/disk/by-uuid/f88e0...4-fe923f01d57c.
         Mounting /boot...
[  OK  ] Mounted /boot.
[  OK  ] Mounted /home.
[  OK  ] Mounted /media/Documentos.
[  OK  ] Mounted /media/Extra.
[  OK  ] Mounted /media/Programas.
[  OK  ] Reached target Local File Systems.
         Starting Security Auditing Service...
         Starting Recreate Volatile Files and Directories...
         Starting Tell Plymouth To Write Out Runtime Data...
         Starting Trigger Flushing of Journal to Persistent Storage...
[  OK  ] Started Security Auditing Service.
[  OK  ] Started Trigger Flushing of Journal to Persistent Storage.
[  OK  ] Started Tell Plymouth To Write Out Runtime Data.
[  OK  ] Started Recreate Volatile Files and Directories.
[  OK  ] Reached target System Initialization.
[  OK  ] Reached target Timers.
         Starting Manage Sound Card State (restore and store)...
[  OK  ] Started Manage Sound Card State (restore and store).
[  OK  ] Reached target Paths.
[  OK  ] Listening on Open-iSCSI iscsiuio Socket.
[  OK  ] Listening on Open-iSCSI iscsid Socket.
[  OK  ] Listening on RPCbind Server Activation Socket.
[  OK  ] Listening on PC/SC Smart Card Daemon Activation Socket.
[  OK  ] Listening on CUPS Printing Service Sockets.
[  OK  ] Listening on D-Bus System Message Bus Socket.
[  OK  ] Reached target Sockets.
[  OK  ] Reached target Basic System.
         Starting firewalld - dynamic firewall daemon...
         Starting Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service...
         Starting Hardware RNG Entropy Gatherer Daemon...
[  OK  ] Started Hardware RNG Entropy Gatherer Daemon.
         Starting irqbalance daemon...
[  OK  ] Started irqbalance daemon.
         Starting NTP client/server...
         Starting ABRT Automated Bug Reporting Tool...
[  OK  ] Started ABRT Automated Bug Reporting Tool.
         Starting ABRT Xorg log watcher...
[  OK  ] Started ABRT Xorg log watcher.
         Starting Builds and install new kmods from akmod packages...
         Starting ABRT kernel log watcher...
[  OK  ] Started ABRT kernel log watcher.
         Starting Machine Check Exception Logging Daemon...
         Starting Install ABRT coredump hook...
         Starting Builds and install new kmods from akmod packages...
         Starting Self Monitoring and Reporting Technology (SMART) Daemon...
[  OK  ] Started Self Monitoring and Reporting Technology (SMART) Daemon.
         Starting Login Service...
         Starting RealtimeKit Scheduling Policy Service...
         Starting Accounts Service...
         Starting Permit User Sessions...
         Starting RPC bind service...
         Starting CUPS Printing Service...
[  OK  ] Started CUPS Printing Service.
         Starting System Logging Service...
[  OK  ] Started System Logging Service.
         Starting D-Bus System Message Bus...
[  OK  ] Started D-Bus System Message Bus.
[  OK  ] Started Machine Check Exception Logging Daemon.
[  OK  ] Started Permit User Sessions.
         Starting Command Scheduler...
[  OK  ] Started Command Scheduler.
         Starting Job spooling tools...
[  OK  ] Started Job spooling tools.
         Starting Wait for Plymouth Boot Screen to Quit...
[  OK  ] Started Install ABRT coredump hook.
[  OK  ] Started RPC bind service.
[  OK  ] Started NTP client/server.
[  OK  ] Started RealtimeKit Scheduling Policy Service.
[  OK  ] Started Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service.
[  OK  ] Started Login Service.
[  OK  ] Started Builds and install new kmods from akmod packages.
[  OK  ] Started Builds and install new kmods from akmod packages.
         Starting The KDE login manager...
[  OK  ] Started The KDE login manager.
[  OK  ] Started Accounts Service.
         Starting Authorization Manager...
```

What should I do to solve my problem?

**Edit:** I can start without problems with GDM. The problem should be in KDM.

Comment: I don't know if it's related but I had something similar happen on my Fedora 19 laptop a few days ago after some updates. Multiple attempts and it would stop late in the boot sequence and never complete. I ended up resolving it by going into rescue and disabling the `abrtd` service from starting at boot. It still delayed late in boot, but it came up after that.

Comment: For my problem, disabling `abrtd` was probably just a kludge but I've been too lazy to go back and figure out what was really happening.

Comment: Instead of disabling `abrtd`, I have set GDM instead KDM, and now it starts as fast as always.
In this case, the problem should be in other place, probably in KDM.

Comment: Is the default in `/etc/inittab` set to `3` or `5`? If you need to do `init 5` then sounds like it might not be...

Comment: The default is `5`. That's why I do `init 3` first. If I only use GDM instead of KDM, it works well.

Comment: Is `inittab` being used at all? What about `ls -l /etc/systemd/system/default.target`?

Answer (score 3):

Probably SELinux is preventing from startup. Mine too was not starting . And here's what I did to solve my problem :

1. Selected  2 option (rescue mode) and press e ;
2. Added 3 in front of .....rhb quiet (Like this : **rhb quiet "3**") and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd>
3. Then I logged in as root in virtual terminal  and typed `startx`  and pressed <kbd>Enter</kbd>
4. Then I was logged in graphically
5. I disabled by SELinux . Like this
   Open terminal, type this:

   ```
   vi /etc/selinux/conf and press enter;
   ```

   Edit the line SELINUX=enforcing to **SELINUX=disabled**
6. Reboot normally and voilà problem solved

Comment: Sorry I don't have enough points to add a comment. Just want to confirm Kunal's answer works perfectly for a similar issue on Fedora 20.

Answer (score 1):

A solution for me on a similar issue on Fedora 20 was to redirect the default target level from the default "graphical" to "multiuser".

This resembles the same initdefault 5 and 3 of the former SysV start sequence.

As I couldn't access the system (a total denial of service both on console and on ssh, although port 22 reported as open to the scans ), I had to start the system from a live CD (used AntiX Linux) and perform the changes from there.

```
root@antiX1:~# cd /mnt
root@antiX1:/mnt# mkdir root
root@antiX1:/mnt# mount /dev/mapper/vg_lv_root /mnt/root
```

*(disk Id above can change in your particular environment; I use LVM)*

```
root@antiX1:/mnt/root# ln -sf /mnt/root/lib/systemd/system/multi-user.target /mnt/root/etc/systemd/system/default.target
root@antiX1:/mnt/root# cd /mnt/root/etc/system
root@antiX1:/mnt/root/etc/systemd/system# ls -l default.target
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 46 Jun  3 17:32 default.target -> /mnt/root/lib/systemd/system/multi-user.target
```

After doing this the system started normally and reached the regular graphical desktop (not clear to me - it was meant to reach a text login prompt, not a GUI).

But I could get 2 failing systems back to production this way.